# How to mass rename folder Debian?

Tags: debian, directory, rename

I have like FOLDERs name like:

```
/AAA1\BBB1\CCC1
/AAA2\BBB2\CCC2
/AAA3\BBB3\CCC3
```

How I can mass rename it to:

```
/AAA1_BBB1_CCC1
/AAA2_BBB2_CCC2
/AAA3_BBB3_CCC3
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

`for folder in AAA*; do mv "$folder" "${folder//\\/_}"; done`

(adjust the AAA* to your pattern).

If you want to test this script before execution add an `echo` before the `mv`.

Comment: @roaima good point, edited my answer to reflect this